# GitLab - unable to view files after adding folder with files to an existing folder

Tags: git, gitlab

I am just learning to use Git and GitLab. I was able to successfully add a folder and sub folders with files using these git commands:

```
$ git add Projects/*
$ git commit -m "Adding all my Work projects"
$ git push
```

Within GitLab, I can drill down to the project name -> file -> folder and then review the file.

I then forgot to add another folder, so I added it to my main folder like so:

```
$ git add Projects/DevQ/*
$ git commit -m "Adding DevQ folder"
$ git push
```

There were no errors on git push, but I cannot find the file within GitLab.
Unlike the initial add, I was able to see "edit-raw-blame-history" buttons on the upper right for the script/file, but after adding another folder, its not there. It just shows download with no file and the buttons "raw-history" in the upper right. Why didn't my files load?

Comment: if you want to add everything try `git add --all`. Make sure `Projects` is not in  `gitignore`

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by `gitignore`. Also, do I need to do a `git push` after doing `git add --all`? thanks.

Comment: yes you do need to `push`. Please read basics of `git` [here](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/) to begin.

Comment: Hmm..I did as you suggested. Doing `git add --all` with a `git push`, but still no luck. All I see is "Download" and no view of the code within GitLab.

Comment: did you `commit`. There are three steps `add` , `commit` and `push`

Comment: yes, I did all three.